# How to calculate least moves of fruit.

Tags: graph-theory, integer-partitions, network

I have a question, I'll try to abstract from the real problem to not lose people. What I'm really looking for is the name of the algorithm or class of problem to find my solution.  I feel that this is some kind of partitioning problem, but that's as far as I have gotten. Here goes.

I've got a table with 10 baskets of fruit.  There are only 3 types of fruit that can be in a basket in any combination: Apple(A), Orange(O), Banana(B).  My goal, is to make all the baskets contain one and only one kind of fruit.  Concerning the baskets, I can have less than I started with but no new baskets can be added.

What is the class of problem this resides in or what algorithm am I looking for.

**Real World Information**:  My company is splitting up and we have 8 database servers(N).  On each of these database servers are databases(duh) which can have three types of ownership Company A, Company B, Shared.  The issue is that the servers contain a mix of differently owned databases, so we can't pack up one box/vm and send it on its way.  So I have been tasked with planning out how to move the servers.  That brings me to the partitioning issue, where I want to move the least dbs possible to achieve uniform ownership on any given server, even if that means I have an empty server.

EDIT: Constraints:  Each server has a maximum size (GB) of data it can hold.

Comment: You must have more constraints, otherwise put all apples in one basket, etc, etc.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah, after writing it, I thought to myself "this question seems ill-posed".

Comment: If you have practically unlimited storage (bottomless basket) on each server then just copy everything for company A to server A, all the data for company B to server B and a third server for all all the shared data.

Comment: if you have only 8 servers "baskets" then you don't need any algorithm: just do it in any way. Efficient algorithms are useful with a big number of items. I guess your real world problem is more complicated to that you asked.

Comment: @GinKin The baskets aren't bottomless, but do have capacity constraints with respect to hard drive space.  This comes into play with the size of the database being moved over.